# func in ngRepeat don't call again after updated more items in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The showFrom function don't called again after each click add button to add more date item in array. It only called at the first time when loading page. This is the problem.

```
<div ng-repeat="da in data" else-if="showFrom(da, '2 Jan 2015')">
             <div>From: {{da}}</div>
          </div>
```

You can copy code below, put in html file and run, it will run good. I have also copied to jsfiddle but not running [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heyokdang/u59360aa/11/),

```
<head>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <button type="button" ng-click="addData()" class="btn btn-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Data
  </button>

  <div ng-repeat="da in data" else-if="showFrom(da, '2 Jan 2015')">
     <div>From: {{da}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.directive('elseIf', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if(scope.$eval(attrs.elseIf)) {
                // remove '<div ng-if...></div>'
                element.replaceWith(element.children())
            } else {
                element.replaceWith(' ')
            }
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.data = ['1 Jan 2013','1 Jan 2014','1 Jan 2015', '1 Jan 2016', '1 Jan 2017', '1 Jan 2018'];

    $scope.showFrom = function(da, db) {
      var da1 = new Date(da);
      var da2 = new Date(db);
      return da1 >= da2;
    };

    var datetest = 2012;
    $scope.addData = function(){
      datetest++;
      var temp = '1 Jun ' + datetest;
      $scope.data.push(temp);
    };

});

//  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and delete the else-if directive, which tries implementing what the standard ng-if directive already does.

Comment: Try using `ng-if` as stated by JB Nizet and your code will work... check this [codePen](http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/OMbeaL)